# How to access trusted HTTPS/SSL server certificate authorities in Java Micro Edition?

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-me, certificate-authority

I am trying to determine which server certificate authorities (CAs) are trusted for a particular phone (Kyocera DuraXT and DuraXTP) for SSL/HTTPS within a Java Micro Edition application (note that this is **NOT** the same as determining trusted certificates for a browser on the device).

Using the following code, you can retrieve information about a specific server certificate for a specific HTTPS connection:

```
HttpsConnection c = null;
InputStream is = null;
c = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open("https://www.website.com/",
Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
is = c.openInputStream();

SecurityInfo secuInfo;

try {
    secuInfo = c.getSecurityInfo();
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(" ProtocolVersion "+secuInfo.getProtocolVersion());
System.out.println(" ProtocolName " + secuInfo.getProtocolName());
System.out.println(" CipherSuite " + secuInfo.getCipherSuite());

Certificate cer = secuInfo.getServerCertificate();
System.out.println(" CA Type " + cer.getType());
System.out.println(" CA Version " + cer.getVersion());
System.out.println(" CA NotAfter " + cer.getNotAfter());
System.out.println(" CA NotBefore " + cer.getNotBefore());
System.out.println(" CA Subject " + cer.getSubject());
System.out.println(" CA Issuer " + cer.getIssuer());
System.out.println(" CA SerialNumber " + cer.getSerialNumber());
```

If this particular CA for this HTTPS connection isn't trusted, a `CertificateException` will be thrown.

Is there a way to determine all the trusted CAs for a J2ME app on a particular device, without trying an actual connection for each one by one?